# CSS Text resize on hover causes sibling element to shift

Tags: css

I have this code and these elements live together in the header of this page. When the hover effects of the `H1#name` take affect the home button gets moved slightly to the right. Is this because of display flex? or is there something I can do to make this home button stay put while the hover effects happen? I've tried a couple position methods so far but none have worked.

```css
#info-header {
    background-color: dimgrey;
    height: 5rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 3rem;
}

#name {
    color: mistyrose;
    font-family: 'Monoton', cursive;
}

#name:hover {
    font-family: 'Monoton', cursive;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transform: scale(1.15);
    transition: 1.75s;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: mistyrose;
}

a:hover {
    color: black;
    opacity: 10%;
}

#home-button {
    height: 2.25rem;
    border-radius: 5%;
    font-weight: 900;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: black;
}

#home-button:hover {
    background-color: mistyrose;
    transition: 1.25s;
}
```

```html
<header id="info-header">
            <h1 id="name">Name</h1>
            <button id="home-button"><a href="index.html">Home</a></button>
        </header>
```

Comment: the problem is with: `text-transform` propery, not with resizing text. Remove it and your animation will work as expected

Comment: if you insist to keep it. you should then add fixed width to your `#name` element.

Comment: Thank you the fixed width did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

add `position: absolute;` and `right: 30%;` to your `#home-button` css. you can adjust the `right` percentage value depending on what you need.

```
#home-button {
    height: 2.25rem;
    border-radius: 5%;
    font-weight: 900;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    right: 30%;
}
```

```css
#info-header {
    background-color: dimgrey;
    height: 5rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 3rem;
}

#name {
    color: mistyrose;
    font-family: 'Monoton', cursive;
}

#name:hover {
    font-family: 'Monoton', cursive;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transform: scale(1.15);
    transition: 1.75s;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: mistyrose;
}

a:hover {
    color: black;
    opacity: 10%;
}

#home-button {
    height: 2.25rem;
    border-radius: 5%;
    font-weight: 900;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    right: 15%;
}

#home-button:hover {
    background-color: mistyrose;
    transition: 1.25s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <header id="info-header">
            <h1 id="name">Name</h1>
            <button id="home-button"><a href="index.html">Home</a></button>
        </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a fixed width to h1#name solved this problem.